# How to group by every 7 rows, and aggregate those 7 values by median?

Tags: r

I have a data frame for daily earning like this:

```
         date    earning
            1 -40.495074
            2 -88.636625
            3 134.400976
            4  66.325253
            5 -86.337511
            6  -1.266815
            7 267.944212
            8  65.247053
            9  86.177537
           10  64.540579
```

I want to group every 7 days and aggregate 7 days earning by using median.

> edit1: It doesn't have to be calendar week, just arbitrary 7 days as as group.

So It would be like

```
week  median-earning
   1  11
   2  22
```

and so on...

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: In your date column, are you using actual dates or just integers?

Comment: It's actual dates. like 2014-9-13, Would convert it to integers be easier?

Comment: Also important to know, when you say every 7 days, do you mean by calendar week?  Or do you want to start on an arbitrary day?

Comment: Sure. doesn't have to be calendar week, just every 7 days started from arbitrary date of the data frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
theData <- data.frame(date = 1:10,
                      earning = c(-40, -88, -134, 66, -86, -1, 267, 65, 86, 64))

theData$seven_day_index <- c(0, rep(1:(nrow(theData)-1)%/%7))

group_by(theData, seven_day_index) %>%
  summarise(median_earnings = median(earning))
```

and the base R version

```
sapply(split(theData$earning, c(0, rep(1:(nrow(theData)-1)%/%7))), median)
```

> edit: inspired by above

```
theData %>% mutate(seven_day_index = 1:nrow(theData) %/% 7) %>%
            group_by(seven_day_index) %>%
            summarise(median_earnings = median(earning)
```

Comment: thanks to @nongkrong for the slick way to get the `seven_day_index`.

Comment: Edited.  Still far cooler than how I normally approach these things.

Comment: Thanks, both Benjamin and nongkrong

Comment: Instead of using a "seven day index", you could also create a "week column": `mutate(week = format(.$date, "%Y/%W"))`. nongkrong's way *is* slick though.

Comment: @Benjamin I was trying your solution with `dplyr` verbs and `theData %>% mutate(seven_day_index = 1:nrow(theData) %/% 7` did not work for me. It seemed to assign index 0 up to the 6th day and on the 7th day the index was 1, not 0.

Comment: slightly modifying the code like this worked: `theData %>% mutate(seven_day_index = 0:(nrow(theData)-1) %/% 7)`